# How to generate certificate in Perforce in Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, perforce

In **Windows** according to 
[docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.superuser.html#DB5-58511)
I set P4SSLDIR:

> set P4SSLDIR=E:\Programs\perforce\P4SSLDIR\

Trying to generate certificate and private key gives error:

> C:\programs>p4d -Gc
>
> Perforce server error:
>           P4SSLDIR not defined or does not reference a valid directory.

How to overcome this to generate priv key and certificate?

Comment: The SSL directory must already exist, and it must be readable ONLY by the user running p4d. Can you verify that those two things are true?

Comment: My current account X is a member of Administrators. P4D is run by this account X. I removed inheritance from Directory P4SSLDIR - now there is only account X in ACL and has full access. Also I changed owner of this directory to X. Also I tried two scenario: 1) running Perforce service p4s as it was - under local service credentials ans 2) run service p4s under account X (Who knows - maybe p4d delegates work to p4s). The error is the same.

Comment: @ Bryan Pendleton: is it possible to perform this command on your Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p4d can not understand **last backslash** in path.

Examples in docs for *nix.
Fix of the problem:

> set P4SSLDIR=E:\Programs\perforce\P4SSLDIR

Incorrect:

> set P4SSLDIR=E:\Programs\perforce\P4SSLDIR\

Comment: Oh, great catch! I'm glad you figured it out. That seems like a bug, to me, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this with a simple experiment (I used Perforce 2013.3, which is the version I happen to have):

```
C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\my-test-server>mkdir P4SSLDIR

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\my-test-server>set P4SSLDIR=C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\my-test-server\P4SSLDIR

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\my-test-server>p4d -Gc

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\my-test-server>dir P4SSLDIR
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 6602-B38E

 Directory of C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\my-test-server\P4SSLDIR

05/24/2015  09:36 AM    <DIR>          .
05/24/2015  09:36 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/24/2015  09:36 AM             1,172 certificate.txt
05/24/2015  09:36 AM             1,704 privatekey.txt
```

You might need to contact Perforce Technical Support for assistance, as it might be something very specific to what you're doing.

Comment: very interesting. Thank you. Will test newer version. my p4d -V gives: Rev. P4D/NTX64/2013.2/708877 (2013/09/18).

Comment: Updated to 2015.1 ver. - the same error. What is your ACL? owner? is user of p4d match those in ACL of target directory? Maybe the issue in parent directories - my have in their ACL other members. But in either case it would be strange to delete Administrators from C:\

Comment: What is your Windows version?

Comment: on virtual machine, on clean Windows 7 installation the same error.